# Overwrite read-only file with the Perl File::Copy function

Tags: perl, copy, readonly

I need to copy read-only files in Perl. I tried using Perl::Copy function, but it fails in case the file already exists and isn't writable.

Is there a force argument I can give to the copy function?

I want to avoid changing permissions of files, or removing the destination file before copying.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you are giving yourself unreasonable requirements.  I think the best solution is to remove the destination file before copying, which should be as simple as:

```
unlink $dest_file if -e $dest_file;
```

Answer (score 0):

with out changing permission you can't overwrite the file.in perl no function for force fully you overwrite

Answer (score 0):

To complete the Ron answer, the [Perl documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/File/Copy.html) says :

> copy will not overwrite read-only files.

That's why we need to change permissions **or** delete file before copy.